# C# Problem: DataGridView properties changed in run-time

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, properties

### Problem:

I have set some properties for datagridview from the interface like column, cell font type, and size but these properties changed in run-time!

### UPDATE:

Setting the properties programmatically has solved the problem.

```
myDataGrid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9.7F, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: Share your code for quick and precise help. There are ways to set properties and you have not told anything that where and how you have set up? how could anyone help without knowing what you have done.

Comment: the question is clear !
i set the properties in design-time but it changes automatically after some time so i decided to set these properties automatically.

Comment: "design-time" makes sense but its not mentioned in question whether settings from designer or manually into <Form>.Designer.cs (autogenerated) or in custom code at run time.

Comment: okay, i edited the question.

Comment: Did you change the value of DataGridView.DataSource after InitializeComponents? This will by default recreate all columns. If you don't want this. Disable DataGridView.AutoGeneratColumns immediately after InitializeComponents, or at least before you set the DataSource

Comment: This is likely related to https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/3033

Comment: @RussKie Yes, it is related, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say given how little information we have to go on - but bear in mind that if they're being set programmatically at runtime, the programmatic settings will override anything you've set in the properties window at design time.

Comment: hmmm, you are right !
So i think it will be better to set these properties programmatically and i will try now .. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to refresh your DataGridView.

Try something like this:

```
dataGrid.Update();
```

or:

```
dataGrid.Refresh();
```